# If statement does not work properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement

This is my code:

```
NSString * atime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[theDataObject.minuteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSLog(@"value of atime is:%@",atime);

if (atime==@"0") {

    NSString * timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@s",[theDataObject.secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.timeLabel.text = timeStr;
}
else {
    NSString * timeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@m%@s",[theDataObject.minuteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row],[theDataObject.secondArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.timeLabel.text = timeStr;
}
```

But it never return first statement only return second statement,even is atim value is  0.

log value:

```
MyAudioRecorder[2484:10703] value of atime is:0
```

also tried to put 0 instead of @"0",still does not work.

Comment: If is not a loop, it has to be `if condition`

Comment: In my career of 7 years I have many person who says if-loop... This is first time I am asking why you say if-loop???

Comment: What's an `if loop` do you mean an `if statement`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (atime==@"0")
```

Compares the **memory address** of `atime` with the address of constant string `@"0"`.

```
if ([atime isEqualToString:@"0"])
```

Compares the **values** that are stored in the two memory locations.

From your requirement it is seen that you want to compare the value not the memory location. So go for 2nd one.

Comment: no problem... and +1 for your question as an award you learnt something.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much for +1 and answer too.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
if ([atime isEqualToString : @" "]) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

**isEqualToString:**  ->

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)aString
```

Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given string is equal to the receiver using a literal **Unicode-based comparison.**

**Discussion** -> When this method compares two strings, if the individual Unicodes are the same, then the strings are equal

For more you can access apple  [NSString Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)

```
if([atime isEqualToString:@"0"])
{
}
else
{
}
```